# JADE with Spring?

Tags: spring, agents-jade

How to use Spring's inversion of control (especially dependency injection) with JADE ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Agent_Development_Framework ), if JADE is managing agent (object) creation with it's platform?

Comment: Hi I will try to solve this, have you done any progress ??

Comment: Not really, I have switched JADE to Akka for actor oriented programming, that can do most (everything?) what JADE can do and has integration with spring as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have the same idea try to look at this
[Spring tutorial with JSE](https://geowarin.github.io/using-spring-in-a-java-se-environment.html) knowing that we implement jade in a JSE environment may be that will work in Spring 3.0

At first glance I personally believe that is possible knowing any agent in jade is a class, spring manages objects we can structure our platform agents where we put the AMS and the DF in a full Java class with it setters and getters and logic.